# C++: Pointer and then roound brackets - what does it mean?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost

I have to make google test for some function wrote by someone else, and I've got situation which I never have before. See pseudocode below:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<CSomeClass> CSomeClass_sh_ptr;
    CSomeClass_sh_ptr getSomething(int A)
    {
        if(A>3)
        {
            return CSomeClass_sh_ptr();
        }
        CSomeClass_sh_ptr pointerToCSomeClass = otherPointerToCSomeClass;
        return pointerToCSomeClass;
    }
```

So my question is - what does

```
CSomeClass_sh_ptr()
```

or

```
boost::shared_ptr<CSomeClass>()
```

mean?

Comment: constructor of `boost::share_ptr<CSomeClass>` type

Comment: @billz: No. Temporary of that type. A constructor is a special function and its declaration (for template types) looks different, plus it has to appear in class scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your context, `CSomeClass_sh_ptr()` is a default constructed instance of `CSomeClass_sh_ptr`. In other words, a default constructed `boost::shared_ptr<CSomeClass>`.

Note that `boost::shared_ptr<SomeClass>` is not a pointer. It is a type that manages a pointer. When default constructed, its managed pointer is NULL or `nullptr`.

Comment: I'm not certain whether it's good teaching to claim that `_ptr< >` is not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Your misconception is that you consider `boost::share_ptr<CSomeClass>` a pointer, while it is actually a `class` managing a pointer to `CSomeClass`, therefore `boost::share_ptr<CSomeClass>()` denotes a construction of object of that class.

Answer (score 1):

The name of a type, followed by a `()`, means to create a temporary of that type, value initialized.  In your case, as others have pointed out, the type is an instantiation of a class template, thus a class.  To value initialize a class is to call its default constructor, if it has one, or to zero-initialize it, if it has no constructors.  (`boost::shared_ptr` has a default constructor, so it gets called).  If you actually had a pointer, to value initialize it would be to zero-initialize it, which would result in a null pointer.  (The default constructor of `boost::shared_ptr` mimics this aspect of pointer behavior; its default constructor creates a shared pointer which behaves like a null pointer.)